# JQuery Interview Online (15 Minutes) TestDome

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function createProductCodeForm(parent) {
  var form = $("<form/>");

  form.append($("<label>").text('Product Code:'));
  form.append($("<input>").attr('name', 'productCode').attr('type', 'text'));
  form.append($("<label>").attr('name', 'hint').text('The product code can be found on the label.'));

  form.append('<br>');

  form.append($("<input>").attr('type', 'submit'));

  parent.append(form);
}
```

The createProductCodeForm function is used to create a new form that accepts a product code from a user.

The current version of the form contains the hint: 'The product code can be found on the label'. This hint is currently always visible to the user.

Improve the form so that the hint is only rendered when the input element is the focused element.

Im having a problem getting this question done since I have little experience with jquery and most of this test has been with javascript / php.

Comment: Super easy but I do not think this is the place to post test questions. You should read up on jQuery.

Comment: Which kind of problem do you have? Can you add a **precise** question?

Answer (score 5):

You can just bind the right attributes to get this all done:

```
function createProductCodeForm(parent) {
  var form = $("<form/>");

  form.append($("<label>").text('Product Code:'));
  form.append($("<input>").attr('name', 'productCode').attr('type', 'text').attr('onfocus','$("label[name]").show()').attr('onblur','$("label[name]").hide()'));
  form.append($("<label>").attr('name', 'hint').text('The product code can be found on the label.').attr('style','display:none'));

  form.append('<br>');

  form.append($("<input>").attr('type', 'submit'));

  parent.append(form);
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/YasirKamdar/pen/xYJdNy

Comment: Can you explain to me how you select using label[name] instead of label[name="hint"] or something? How does name only let you find the label you want?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create event handlers for the focus/blur events:

```js
function createProductCodeForm(parent) {
  var form = $("<form/>");
  var input = $("<input>")
                .attr('name', 'productCode')
                .attr('type', 'text');

  var label = $("<label>")
                .attr('name', 'hint')
                .text('The product code can be found on the label.')
                .hide();

  form.append($("<label>").text('Product Code:'));
  form.append(input);
  form.append(label);
 
  input.focus(label.show.bind(label));
  input.blur(label.hide.bind(label));
  
  form.append('<br>');
  form.append($("<input>").attr('type', 'submit'));
  parent.append(form);
}

createProductCodeForm($('#formContainer'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="formContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Bootstrap plugin to do the task.

```js
function createProductCodeForm(parent) {
  var form = $("<form/>");

  form.append($("<label>").text('Product Code:'));
  var $productCode = $('<input />'); 
  $productCode.attr({'name' : 'productCode', 'type': 'text'});
  // use Bootstrap tooltip plugin:
  $productCode.tooltip({'trigger':'focus', 'title': 'The product code can be found on the label.', 'placement':'right'});
  form.append($productCode);
  form.append('<br>');

  form.append($("<input>").attr('type', 'submit'));

  parent.append(form);
}

createProductCodeForm($('body'))
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for the element in html should set the class or id to confirm the correct object(ex input:txtInput ,label :lblHint). So I think the code should look like this:

```
function createProductCodeForm(parent) {
  var form = $("<form></form>");

  form.append($("<label>").text('Product Code:'));
  form.append($("<input>").attr('name', 'productCode').attr('type', 'text').attr('id', 'txtInput'));
  form.append($("<label>").attr('name', 'hint').css("display", "none").attr('id', 'lblHint').text('The product code can be found on the label.'));
  form.append('<br>');
  form.append($("<input>").attr('type', 'submit'));
  parent.append(form);
  $("#txtInput").focusin(function() {
    $("#lblHint").show();
  });
  $("#txtInput").focusout(function() {
    $("#lblHint").hide();
  });
}
```